# Не работает поиск, почему?

Tags: javascript, html

Когда ввожу названия валют в инпуте ничего не работает, не понимаю почему, помогите пожалуйста

```js
const curscr = document.getElementById('curscr');
const filter = curscr.value.toLowerCase();
const curblock = document.getElementById('currency__info');
const curname = document.getElementById('currency');

curscr.oninput = function() {

  if (curname[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
    curblock[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    curblock[i].style.display = "none";
  }

};
```

```html
<div class="currency__prices">
  <input type="text" id="curscr" placeholder="Search cryptocurrency...">

  <a href="charts/eth.html">
    <div class="currency__info">
      <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/eth.svg">
        <span id="currency">Ethereum (ETH)</span>
        <span id="ethBal">0.00</span>
      </div>
      <div class="s__data">
        <span id="ethPrice"></span>
        <span id="ethChange"></span>
        <span id="ethVol"><span>(Volume)</span></span>
        <span id="ethCap"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="charts/btc.html">
    <div class="currency__info">
      <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/btc.svg">
        <span id="currency">Bitcoin (BTC)</span>
        <span id="btcBal">0.2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="s__data">
        <span id="btcPrice"></span>
        <span id="btcChange"></span>
        <span id="btcVol"></span>
        <span id="btcCap"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/usdt.svg">
      <span id="currency">Tether (USDT)</span>
      <span id="usdtBal">150.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="usdtPrice"></span>
      <span id="usdtChange"></span>
      <span id="usdtVol"></span>
      <span id="usdtCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/BNB.svg">
      <span id="currency">Binance (BNB)</span>
      <span id="bnbBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="bnbPrice"></span>
      <span id="bnbChange"></span>
      <span id="bnbVol"></span>
      <span id="bnbCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/sol.svg">
      <span id="currency">Solana (SOL)</span>
      <span id="solBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="solPrice"></span>
      <span id="solChange"></span>
      <span id="solVol"></span>
      <span id="solCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/xrp.svg">
      <span id="currency">Ripple (XRP)</span>
      <span id="xrpBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="xrpPrice"></span>
      <span id="xrpChange"></span>
      <span id="xrpVol"></span>
      <span id="xrpCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/usdc.svg">
      <span id="currency">USDC (USDC)</span>
      <span id="usdcBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="usdcPrice"></span>
      <span id="usdcChange"></span>
      <span id="usdcVol"></span>
      <span id="usdcCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/lido.svg">
      <span id="currency">Lido Staked Ether (STETH)</span>
      <span id="stethBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="stethPrice"></span>
      <span id="stethChange"></span>
      <span id="stethVol"></span>
      <span id="stethCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/ada.svg">
      <span id="currency">Cardano (ADA)</span>
      <span id="adaBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="adaPrice"></span>
      <span id="adaChange"></span>
      <span id="adaVol"></span>
      <span id="adaCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/doge.svg">
      <span id="currency">Dogecoin (DOGE)</span>
      <span id="dogeBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="dogePrice"></span>
      <span id="dogeChange"></span>
      <span id="dogeVol"></span>
      <span id="dogeCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/trx.svg">
      <span id="currency">Tron (TRX)</span>
      <span id="trxBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="trxPrice"></span>
      <span id="trxChange"></span>
      <span id="trxVol"></span>
      <span id="trxCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/matic.svg">
      <span id="currency">Polygon (MATIC)</span>
      <span id="maticBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="maticPrice"></span>
      <span id="maticChange"></span>
      <span id="maticVol"></span>
      <span id="maticCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/dai.svg">
      <span id="currency">Dai (DAI)</span>
      <span id="daiBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="daiPrice"></span>
      <span id="daiChange"></span>
      <span id="daiVol"></span>
      <span id="daiCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/dot.svg">
      <span id="currency">Polkadot (DOT)</span>
      <span id="dotBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="dotPrice"></span>
      <span id="dotChange"></span>
      <span id="dotVol"></span>
      <span id="dotCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/ltc.svg">
      <span id="currency">Litecoin (LTC)</span>
      <span id="ltcBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="ltcPrice"></span>
      <span id="ltcChange"></span>
      <span id="ltcVol"></span>
      <span id="ltcCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/bch.svg">
      <span id="currency">Bitcoin Cash (BCH)</span>
      <span id="bchBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="bchPrice"></span>
      <span id="bchChange"></span>
      <span id="bchVol"></span>
      <span id="bchCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/shib.svg">
      <span id="currency">Shiba Inu (SHIB)</span>
      <span id="shibBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="shibPrice"></span>
      <span id="shibChange"></span>
      <span id="shibVol"></span>
      <span id="shibCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/link.svg">
      <span id="currency">Chain Link (LINK)</span>
      <span id="linkBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="linkPrice"></span>
      <span id="linkChange"></span>
      <span id="linkVol"></span>
      <span id="linkCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/leo.svg">
      <span id="currency">Unus Sed Leo (LEO)</span>
      <span id="leoBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="leoPrice"></span>
      <span id="leoChange"></span>
      <span id="leoVol"></span>
      <span id="leoCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/tusd.svg">
      <span id="currency">TrueUSD (TUSD)</span>
      <span id="tusdBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="tusdPrice"></span>
      <span id="tusdChange"></span>
      <span id="tusdVol"></span>
      <span id="tusdCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/avax.svg">
      <span id="currency">Avalanche (AVAX)</span>
      <span id="avaxBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="avaxPrice"></span>
      <span id="avaxChange"></span>
      <span id="avaxVol"></span>
      <span id="avaxCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/xlm.svg">
      <span id="currency">Stellar (XLM)</span>
      <span id="xlmBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="xlmPrice"></span>
      <span id="xlmChange"></span>
      <span id="xlmVol"></span>
      <span id="xlmCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
      <img src="assets-w/xmr.svg">
      <span id="currency">Monero (XMR)</span>
      <span id="xmrBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
      <span id="xmrPrice"></span>
      <span id="xmrChange"></span>
      <span id="xmrVol"></span>
      <span id="xmrCap"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('currency__info')` возвращает один элемент. И ID долно быть уникально во всем DOM( не должно быть 2 и более одинаковых ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не использовали цикл для перебора элементов с классом currency__info и надо проверять, соответствует ли текст элемента введенному фильтру.

```js
const curscr = document.getElementById('curscr');
const curblocks = document.getElementsByClassName('currency__info');
const curnames = document.querySelectorAll('.currency__info #currency');

curscr.oninput = function () {
    const filter = curscr.value.toLowerCase();

    for (let i = 0; i < curblocks.length; i++) {
        if (curnames[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
            curblocks[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            curblocks[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="currency__prices">
    <input type="text" id="curscr" placeholder="Search cryptocurrency...">

    <div class="currency__info">
        <div class="f__data">
            <img src="assets-w/eth.svg">
            <span id="currency">Ethereum (ETH)</span>
            <span id="ethBal">0.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="s__data">
            <span id="ethPrice"></span>
            <span id="ethChange"></span>
            <span id="ethVol"><span>(Volume)</span></span>
            <span id="ethCap"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/btc.svg">
        <span id="currency">Bitcoin (BTC)</span>
        <span id="btcBal">0.2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="btcPrice"></span>
        <span id="btcChange"></span>
        <span id="btcVol"></span>
        <span id="btcCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/usdt.svg">
        <span id="currency">Tether (USDT)</span>
        <span id="usdtBal">150.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="usdtPrice"></span>
        <span id="usdtChange"></span>
        <span id="usdtVol"></span>
        <span id="usdtCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/BNB.svg">
        <span id="currency">Binance (BNB)</span>
        <span id="bnbBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="bnbPrice"></span>
        <span id="bnbChange"></span>
        <span id="bnbVol"></span>
        <span id="bnbCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/sol.svg">
        <span id="currency">Solana (SOL)</span>
        <span id="solBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="solPrice"></span>
        <span id="solChange"></span>
        <span id="solVol"></span>
        <span id="solCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/xrp.svg">
        <span id="currency">Ripple (XRP)</span>
        <span id="xrpBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="xrpPrice"></span>
        <span id="xrpChange"></span>
        <span id="xrpVol"></span>
        <span id="xrpCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/usdc.svg">
        <span id="currency">USDC (USDC)</span>
        <span id="usdcBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="usdcPrice"></span>
        <span id="usdcChange"></span>
        <span id="usdcVol"></span>
        <span id="usdcCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/lido.svg">
        <span id="currency">Lido Staked Ether (STETH)</span>
        <span id="stethBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="stethPrice"></span>
        <span id="stethChange"></span>
        <span id="stethVol"></span>
        <span id="stethCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/ada.svg">
        <span id="currency">Cardano (ADA)</span>
        <span id="adaBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="adaPrice"></span>
        <span id="adaChange"></span>
        <span id="adaVol"></span>
        <span id="adaCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/doge.svg">
        <span id="currency">Dogecoin (DOGE)</span>
        <span id="dogeBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="dogePrice"></span>
        <span id="dogeChange"></span>
        <span id="dogeVol"></span>
        <span id="dogeCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/trx.svg">
        <span id="currency">Tron (TRX)</span>
        <span id="trxBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="trxPrice"></span>
        <span id="trxChange"></span>
        <span id="trxVol"></span>
        <span id="trxCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/matic.svg">
        <span id="currency">Polygon (MATIC)</span>
        <span id="maticBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="maticPrice"></span>
        <span id="maticChange"></span>
        <span id="maticVol"></span>
        <span id="maticCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/dai.svg">
        <span id="currency">Dai (DAI)</span>
        <span id="daiBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="daiPrice"></span>
        <span id="daiChange"></span>
        <span id="daiVol"></span>
        <span id="daiCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/dot.svg">
        <span id="currency">Polkadot (DOT)</span>
        <span id="dotBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="dotPrice"></span>
        <span id="dotChange"></span>
        <span id="dotVol"></span>
        <span id="dotCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/ltc.svg">
        <span id="currency">Litecoin (LTC)</span>
        <span id="ltcBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="ltcPrice"></span>
        <span id="ltcChange"></span>
        <span id="ltcVol"></span>
        <span id="ltcCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/bch.svg">
        <span id="currency">Bitcoin Cash (BCH)</span>
        <span id="bchBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="bchPrice"></span>
        <span id="bchChange"></span>
        <span id="bchVol"></span>
        <span id="bchCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/shib.svg">
        <span id="currency">Shiba Inu (SHIB)</span>
        <span id="shibBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="shibPrice"></span>
        <span id="shibChange"></span>
        <span id="shibVol"></span>
        <span id="shibCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/link.svg">
        <span id="currency">Chain Link (LINK)</span>
        <span id="linkBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="linkPrice"></span>
        <span id="linkChange"></span>
        <span id="linkVol"></span>
        <span id="linkCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/leo.svg">
        <span id="currency">Unus Sed Leo (LEO)</span>
        <span id="leoBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="leoPrice"></span>
        <span id="leoChange"></span>
        <span id="leoVol"></span>
        <span id="leoCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/tusd.svg">
        <span id="currency">TrueUSD (TUSD)</span>
        <span id="tusdBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="tusdPrice"></span>
        <span id="tusdChange"></span>
        <span id="tusdVol"></span>
        <span id="tusdCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/avax.svg">
        <span id="currency">Avalanche (AVAX)</span>
        <span id="avaxBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="avaxPrice"></span>
        <span id="avaxChange"></span>
        <span id="avaxVol"></span>
        <span id="avaxCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/xlm.svg">
        <span id="currency">Stellar (XLM)</span>
        <span id="xlmBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="xlmPrice"></span>
        <span id="xlmChange"></span>
        <span id="xlmVol"></span>
        <span id="xlmCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="currency__info" id="currency__info">
    <div class="f__data">
        <img src="assets-w/xmr.svg">
        <span id="currency">Monero (XMR)</span>
        <span id="xmrBal">0.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="s__data">
        <span id="xmrPrice"></span>
        <span id="xmrChange"></span>
        <span id="xmrVol"></span>
        <span id="xmrCap"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```